# React Context API undefined in production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx, webpacker

[Edit] I realised this is due to an issue that is outside of React. Please ignore this question.

I am using React Context for my project. It works perfectly on my application on development environment with Webpacker but when I precompile my assets to serve my application in production environment it throw me `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'n.context.user.username')` error. I tried implementing all the suggested solutions but it still didn't work. I upgrade the versions: to `"react": "^16.7.0", "react-dom": "^16.6.0"` and defining the Context creation in a separate file. The app will work fine if we use  but want to stick to try our best to stick to the contextType method. Would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Here are the links for the code:

Context Creation
https://github.com/VantageSG/Vantage/blob/master/app/javascript/contexts/UserContext.jsx

Context Provider
https://github.com/VantageSG/Vantage/blob/master/app/javascript/components/App.jsx

Context Consumer
https://github.com/VantageSG/Vantage/blob/master/app/javascript/components/navBar/desktopNavBar.jsx

Comment: You need to use the same version for react and react-dom

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I still get the same error after changing react version to `16.6.0` :(