# NextJS: Context values undefined in production (works fine in development)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-context

A "dark mode" feature has been implemented on my `Next.js` application using `React's Context api`.

Everything works fine during development, however, `Context provider`-related problems have arisen on the built version — global states show as `undefined` and cannot be handled.

---

`_app.tsx` is wrapped with the `ThemeProvider` as such:

```
// React & Next hooks
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

// Irrelevant imports

// Global state management
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "../redux/store";
import { AuthProvider } from "../context/UserContext";
import { ThemeProvider } from "../context/ThemeContext";

// Components
import Layout from "../components/Layout/Layout";
import Footer from "../components/Footer/Footer";

// Irrelevant code

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const router = useRouter();

  // Applying different layouts depending on page
  switch (Component.name) {
    case "HomePage":
      return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <ThemeProvider>
            <AuthProvider>
              <Component {...pageProps} />
              <Footer color="fff" />
            </AuthProvider>
          </ThemeProvider>
        </Provider>
      );
    case "PageNotFound":
      return (
        <>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
          <Footer color="#f2f2f5" />
        </>
      );

    default:
      // Irrelevant code
  }
}
export default MyApp;
```

The `ThemeContext` correctly exports both its `Provider` and `Context`:

```
import { createContext, ReactNode, useState, useEffect } from "react";

type themeContextType = {
  darkMode: boolean | null;
  toggleDarkMode: () => void;
};

type Props = {
  children: ReactNode;
};

// Checks for user's preference.
const getPrefColorScheme = () => {
  return !window.matchMedia
    ? null
    : window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches;
};

// Gets previously stored theme if it exists.
const getInitialMode = () => {
  const isReturningUser = "dark-mode" in localStorage; // Returns true if user already used the website.
  const savedMode = localStorage.getItem("dark-mode") === "true" ? true : false;
  const userPrefersDark = getPrefColorScheme(); // Gets user's colour preference.

  // If mode was saved ► return saved mode else get users general preference.
  return isReturningUser ? savedMode : userPrefersDark ? true : false;
};

export const ThemeContext = createContext<themeContextType>(
  {} as themeContextType
);

export const ThemeProvider = ({ children }: Props) => {
  // localStorage only exists on the browser (window), not on the server
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState<boolean | null>(null);

  // Getting theme from local storage upon first render
  useEffect(() => {
    setDarkMode(getInitialMode);
  }, []);

  // Prefered theme stored in local storage
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("dark-mode", JSON.stringify(darkMode));
  }, [darkMode]);

  const toggleDarkMode = () => {
    setDarkMode(!darkMode);
  };

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ darkMode, toggleDarkMode }}>
      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

The `ThemeToggler` responsible for updating the `darkMode` state operates properly during development (theme toggled and correct value `console.log`ed upon clicking), however it doesn't do anything during production (`console.log`s an `undefined` state):

```
import React, { FC, useContext } from "react";
import { ThemeContext } from "../../context/ThemeContext";

const ThemeToggler: FC = () => {
  const { darkMode, toggleDarkMode } = useContext(ThemeContext);

  const toggleTheme = () => {
    console.log(darkMode) // <--- darkMode is undefined during production
    toggleDarkMode();
  };
  return (
    <div className="theme-toggler">
      <i
        className={`fas ${darkMode ? "fa-sun" : "fa-moon"}`}
        data-testid="dark-mode"
        onClick={toggleTheme}
      ></i>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ThemeToggler;
```

The solutions/suggestions I've looked up before posting this were to no avail.

[React Context API undefined in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60223841/react-context-api-undefined-in-production) — `react` and `react-dom` are on the same version.

Thanks in advance.

---

P.S. For those wondering why I am using both `Redux` and `Context` for global state management:

- `Context` is best suited for low-frequency and simple state updates such as *themes* and *authentication*.
- `Redux` is better for high-frequency and complex state updates in addition to providing a better debugging tool — `Redux DevTools`.

P.S.2 Yes, it is better – performance-wise – to install FontAwesome's dependencies rather than use a CDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for sharing the code. It's well written. By reading it i don't see any problem. Based on your component topology, as long as your `ThemeToggler` is defined under any page component, your `darkMode` can't be `undefined`.

Here's your topology of  the site

```
  <MyApp>
    <Provider>
      // A. will not work
      <ThemeProvider>
        <HomePage>
          // B. should work
        </HomePage>
      </ThemeProvider>
      // C. will not work
    </Provider>
  </MyApp>
```

Although your `ThemeProvider` is a custom provider, inside `ThemeContext.Provider` is defined with value `{{ darkMode, toggleDarkMode }}`. So in theory you can't get `undefined` unless your component `ThemeToggler` is not under a `HomePage` component. I marked two non working locations, any component put under location A or C will give you `undefined`.

Since you have a condition for `HomePage`, you can run into this problem if you are on other pages. So in general you should wrap the `ThemeProvider` on top of your router.

```
  <ThemeProvider>
    <AuthProvider>
      {Component.name != "PageNotFound" && (
         <Component {...pageProps} />
      )}
    </AuthProvider>
  </ThemeProvider>
```

You get the point, you want to first go through a layer that theme always exist before you fire up a router.

You can confirm if  this is the case by doing the following test.

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider>
      <AuthProvider>
         <Component {...pageProps} />
      </AuthProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

If this works in production, then it confirms it. To be honest, this problem also exists in the dev, however maybe due to your routes change too quickly, it normally hides these issues.

Comment: I appreciate your detailed reply windmaomao! Your solution fixed my problem, it was indeed because of not having wrapped the other pages with the providers. This was a problem as well with the layout, development and production had given different results.

Comment: Kool, I'm glad it helped :) I was also scratching my head why you can get an `undefined` from a well written provider.